# ¿Como guardar un valor en variable y en un archivo a la vez en Unix?

Tags: linux, script, unix

Ante todo disculpad si no soy técnico del todo cuando pregunto esto.

Necesito que la búsqueda de un `grep` me devuelva un valor a un archivo y lo introduzca ahí pero además necesito que de alguna manera me meta ese valor en una variable para luego poder sumarlo. Me explico, tengo lo siguiente:

```
echo -e "RC=200: \t `grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006* | xargs grep 'RC=200' | wc -l`" > ${RUTA}/fallos_202006.txt
```

Ese `grep` me consigue sacar la cantidad de logs de programas fallados del mes de junio con un formato así:

```
RC=200: 395
```

Eso estaría perfecto, pero como tengo mas grep como ese que busca cada uno una cosa diferente, necesito que ademas de sacar eso mismo en el archivo, me saque el numero a una variable para luego poder añadir una linea que sea algo así como: `"Sumatorio de todos los fallos: XXX"`

He intentado añadir con `>` y declarando `fallo200=0` y no me funciona.

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me autocontesto.

La solucion era dividirlo en dos, con una variable en el medio:

> `rc200=$(bzgrep -lZ 'grep -lZ 'Job failed' /logs/programas/*202006* | xargs grep 'RC=200' | wc -l)`

`echo -e "RC=200: \t $rc200" > ${RUTA}/fallos_202006.txt`

con esto funciona a la perfeccción si luego quieres sumar esa variable con otra